# How can I send verification code in email instead of sms using authy?

Tags: php, email, sms, twilio, authy

I am using twilio authy API with PHP for sending verification code to the user in sms where Authy handles everything  generation of a new code, sending to mobile and verification using its various APIs but now I need Authy to send code in email instead of sending code in SMS and all other features will be same like verification and generation of code at authy level.

How can I do that? Or can anybody suggest to me some other third party for that?

Actually I don't want to generate code myself and save it in my database but should be handled by some third party.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The Authy API only supports sending 2FA codes over [SMS, a voice call, via the application](https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy/api/one-time-passwords#request-a-one-time-password) or over [push notifications](https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy/api/push-authentications). You cannot send 2FA codes over email using the Authy API.

Answer (score 0):

You can send verification code via email using Twilio Authy api. Authy added support for this- https://www.twilio.com/changelog/authy-adds-support-user-authentication-email